# Autosize height of textview and container biew

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a chat application and need a textview field to input the chat message.  The textView is embedded in a view that should move up/down with the keyboard when text editing begin/end.  How can I make the textview dynamically adjust height so that it accommodates the length of text, while also adjusting the dar grey container view according to the height of the textview.  It should basically work and look like the Messages or Slack app.

I tried

inputTextView.sizeToFit()

in viewDidLoad of the corresponding ViewController, but the container view and texfield have the same size as far as I can tell

Any help is much appreciated - thank you

[image]

Comment: take outlet of height constraint of a view that contains `textview` and update constant value in `textViewDidChange` method

Comment: @ei-captain-v2-0 Thanks, I tried that but the height of the textview and the view jumps around
textFieldViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.height